# Keystore Explorer 5.1.1 Could not open certificate file CRT(that already signed by organization)

Tags: csr

I created a CSR file via Keystore Explorer5.1.1 and sent the CSR to authority organization. The organization returned me certificated CRT file and I got the CRT to Examine by Keystore Explorer, which reported an error:

[image]

Comment: I created CSR file by signature algorithm SHA-256 with RSA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your post to add the detail you put in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Version 5.1.1 is more than two years old and it had some problems with PEM encoded certificate files. A newer version of KeyStore Explorer could probably open this file.

But this is not the right way to import the certificate from the CA anyway. Instead follow these steps:

1. Open the keystore with the key pair.
2. Right click on the key and select "Import CA Reply"
3. Select the certificate file.